# Is there a way to display a report (without a chart) on a Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've been trying to use an iframe to embed a report into a VF page, but it hasn't been displaying. What's the easiest way to go about this? (hopefully without having to create a separate apex class/working in a sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put Salesforce into an iframe, even in Visualforce. This is a security feature. The only real "non-Apex" alternative is to call the REST API to run the report, which is further complicated by the need to call it through the AJAX Proxy API. By the time you get around to doing all this, you may as well have spun up the sandbox and write the Apex Code you were hoping to avoid; it'd probably take less time.

As an aside, if you're not familiar with it yet, you should start learning [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx); once you've learned the basics, you'll never think that spinning up a sample org to write some code would take too much effort. In fact, if you haven't already, I'd suggest you get started migrating to a DX repo as soon as possible. The amount of time it can save you is pretty impressive.